# Sphere eversion in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, spheres, orientation

I know it's possible to perform a sphere eversion is $\mathbb R^3$, if we allow self-intersections.

My question is: it's possible to perform a sphere ($S^2$) eversion in $\mathbb R^4$, without self-intersection? If yes, how?

Comment: An eversion of a $3$-sphere?

Comment: No, I mean $S^2$

Comment: What exactly does eversion mean in that context?

Comment: Bring the inner side outside

Comment: But the two-sphere does not split that space into an inside and an outside...

Comment: Okay, but if, for example, I take the circle $S^1$ in $R^3$ it also doesn't split the space, but it has an inner and outer side in the plane where it lives. So I suppose that if I take $S^2$ in $R^4$ it has two side in the hyperplane where it lives. Am I totally wrong?

Comment: But that is not the inside and outside in any sensible sense of the words...

Comment: If I go to the circus I can see a tiger jumping _inside_ a circle, with the idea that this is the "inside" in the plane where there is the circle

Comment: The whole point of eversions of $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$ is that the space of embeddings of the first in the second is disconnected, and what is surprising is that the two components are connected in the space of immersions. In your case, the space of embeddings o $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^4$ is already connected so there is not much happening...

Comment: So it is possible?

Comment: What is possible?

Comment: If you think about the analogous case $S^1 \to R^3$ a bit more, you should find that the "eversion" can simply be performed by a half-rotation of the circle about some axis contained in the plane of the circle, since the end result of this rotation is simply a reflection in the plane of interest. This should directly generalize: any reflection of the 3-dimensional subspace containing your $S^2$ in $R^4$ can be generated by a continuous rotation of $R^4$, and composing two reflections gives you the inversion map.

Comment: But a rotation will flip inside and outside? I imagine $S^1$ with many little arrows pointing inside: if I move it rigidly, for example if I rotate it, will not the arrows keep pointing inside?